# count nubmers of subfield of repeatert ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i want to count number of  sub field of repeater ACF
thas my code

```
<?php
   $cards = get_sub_field('agence_post');
   if(have_rows('agence_post')):
      $number_of_cards = count($cards);
      echo $number_of_cards;
  endif;
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count the total number of rows in a ACF repeater output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43788167/how-to-count-the-total-number-of-rows-in-a-acf-repeater-output)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hello You can get no of subfields by using this function

```
<?php $numrows = count( get_sub_field( 'agence_post' ) );
  echo $numrows;?>
```